# Memory allocated when accessing CoreData to-many relationship not released?

Tags: ios, core-data, memory-management, one-to-many, nsmanagedobject

I'm building a news app where you have a series of images representing the actual articles. When you tap one of them, it opens up the main article page, which has a scroll view on the bottom containing related articles.

I found a strange (possibly CoreData related) problem regarding said bottom scroller. When I open the article page, I fetch the related articles, allocate a series of `articleViewControllers` and add their views to the scroll view. When I switch from the article page, I remove all the views from the scroller and release the `articleViewControllers`. Upon using Instruments and a couple of heapshots (one before tapping an article and another when switching back to the main page), I found that a substantial amount of memory remains allocated (see images)

[image]

[image]

When viewing the non-object tab, I discover that most of the allocations happen at the following line of code, in the `viewDidLoad` method of the above mentioned `articleViewController`:

```
    NSSet *tempSet = [[NSSet alloc] initWithSet:tempArticle.thumb];
    //tempArticle.thumb is the actual problem here
    [tempSet release]
```

`tempArticle` is an instance of the `Article` class, a subclass of NSManagedObject.
If I comment out these two lines of code, everything works fine, so I'm guessing it's a consequence of faulty CoreData usage.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Core Data handles its own memory management. It may keep objects in memory or purge them at its own whim.

It's recommended that you not store large BLOBs (such as images) in NSManagedObjects. Instead,  store the images to disk, with its filepath reference in an NSManagedObject.

Comment: Or use the new allow external storage checkbox.

Comment: Hey that's pretty cool! Worth noting that sadly it's only available in iOS 5+ so I won't get to take advantage of it for a while =(

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, but that's not the issue here. I'm already using the external storage to save the images and saving the path in an NSString property.